# How Can I Use "history.push" In This Situation? react-router-dom V5

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a snippet of code that somewhat looks like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-field-4jwmxc?file=/src/SomeFile.js

```
// SomeFile.js

import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

/*
Cannot put it here either
const history = useHistory();
*/

export const SomeFile = () => {
  console.log("something?");
  handlers.SWITCH_PAGE();
};

const handlers = {
  SWITCH_PAGE: () => {
    try {
      console.log("triggered");
      /*
      const history = useHistory();
      Cannot put it here
      */
      history.push({
        pathname: "/someLocation"
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }
};

export default SomeFile;
```

This is just how the file was designed.

I am attempting to make the history.push go to another page but due to the rules of React Hook, it will not let me.

I tried putting the redirect in its own file but that also did not work: https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-hypatia-c1fli1?file=/src/SomeFile.js

```
// Redirect.js

import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

export const Redirect = (redirect) => {
  function Redir(redirect) {
    try {
      const history = useHistory();
      history.push(redirect);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }

  Redir(redirect);

  return <></>;
};

export default Redirect;
```

```
// SomeFile.js

import Redirect from "./Redirect";

export const SomeFile = () => {
  console.log("something?");
  handlers.SWITCH_PAGE();
};

const handlers = {
  SWITCH_PAGE: () => {
    try {
      console.log("triggered");

      /*
      history.push({
        pathname: "/someLocation"
      });
      */
      Redirect("/someLocation");
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }
};

export default SomeFile;
```

What can I do to get around this?

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [ask] and how to make a [mre]. Don't put links to code, include it in the question.

Comment: Just declare the `SomeFile` function in the `Home` component so it can use the `useHistory` hook. Please also edit your question to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the relevant code you have an issue working with.

Comment: @DrewReese The example I put is supposed to mimmick the real file, I wouldnt be able to do that

Comment: You can't use the `useHistory` hook in the component and issue a `history.push` in a callback?

Comment: @DrewReese Sorry, dont quite understand. What do you mean?

Comment: Follow the Rules of Hooks, move the `useHistory` hook call into the component you are trying to do the navigation action in, and then issue a `history.push` in *that* component where you are trying to use this utility function that doesn't work.

Comment: @DrewReese The problem is, the main function is not "Home", the main function is "SomeFile". Its technically a file with a bunch of functions that are called when a push notification is triggered. If im understanding wrong, can you show me some psudo code?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to access the `history` object *outside* a React component you've basically a couple options.

- Create a global custom history object that your router uses and that can be imported for use in code external to React.

  1. Create and export a custom history object to match the router being used.

     ```
     import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

     const history = createBroswerHistory();

     export default history;
     ```
  2. Import the `history` object and pass it to your app's router.

     ```
     import {
       Router, // <-- low-level router
       Switch,
       Route
     } from "react-router-dom";
     import history from "../path/to/history";

     export default function App() {
       return (
         <Router history={history}> // <-- pass history as prop
           <Switch>
             <Route path="/SomeLocation">
               <SomeLocation />
             </Route>
             <Route path="/">
               <Home />
             </Route>
           </Switch>
         </Router>
       );
     }
     ```
  3. Import the `history` object to your utility code.

     ```
     import history from "../path/to/history";

     export const someFile = () => {
       console.log("something?");
       handlers.SWITCH_PAGE();
     };

     const handlers = {
       SWITCH_PAGE: () => {
         try {
           console.log("triggered");
           history.push("/someLocation");
         } catch (e) {
           console.error(e);
         }
       }
     };

     export default someFile;
     ```
- Pass `history` in to the utility function for it to use.

  ```
  export const someFile = ({ history }) => {
    console.log("something?");
    handlers.SWITCH_PAGE({ history });
  };

  const handlers = {
    SWITCH_PAGE: ({ history }) => {
      try {
        console.log("triggered");
        history.push("/someLocation");
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
    }
  };

  export default someFile;
  ```

  In component using the `someFile` utility function, use the `useHistory` hook to access the `history` object and pass to the utility.

  ```
  import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
  import someFile from '../path/to/someFile';

  const Component = () => {
    const history = useHistory();

    ...

    const callback = () => {
      ...
      someFile(history);
      ...
    };

    ...
  };
  ```